# Combining multiple correlated variables into a "score"

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, predictive-models

I have connected some sensors to a machine that is continuosly producing a "product". Every minute, there are about 15-16 different metrics that I collect, such as speed, rpm, temperature, ampere, product-diameter etc..
These all have different scales. RPM might be >1000 while another metric is <1.

Some of the time, the product quality is great. Some other times, like if the machine was idle for a while, the product quality is really bad before the machine has warmed up, and the product has to be thrown away.

I am trying to model a function that takes input from these 15-16 different variables, and outputs one single metric, a product quality "score".

(I think) my goal is to find the relations of the variables and how they affect each other and the quality score. So for example if *variable1* fluctuates just a little, it has big negative impact on the score. But if another *variable2* fluctuates, it might not even affect the score at all.

As all the metrics are related to eachother, I am confident this is possible to model. But I am not sure which approach to take?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You're looking for a quality score... but how do you define "quality" in the first place? You need to know what you want subjectively or qualitatively before you can ask how to obtain it quantitatively.

Comment: Quality is assessed manually. So I could probably tag the data with good vs bad, and do some supervised learning?

Comment: That's the only way I can see to proceed. You could also use ["semi-supervised" learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) although I don't know much about it myself.