# Calculate score for multiple variables

Tags: z-score, scoring-rules, real-time

My question is similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205566/combining-multiple-variables-into-one-score).

I have a large geographical area divided 
into small cells (approximately 2.25 km$^2$). I'm calculating some value (heat) for individual cells dynamically. It is an integer value.

We have some people going through these cells.

I want to calculate a score for these people based on their visits to cells. 
This score should tell how each person spent their time with an idea about cells  visited. So according to the example below person A should have higher score than person B or vice versa.

As a example, suppose there are 2 people (A, B).

A visits cell C1 and stays there 3 minutes, then visits  C2 for 4 minutes and finally visits  C3 for 2 minutes.

B visits C4 for 3 minutes, then C5 for 4 minutes and finally C6 for 2 minutes.

If the heat values for those cells are

- C1 : 8
- C2 : 6
- C3 : 7
- C4 : 2
- C5 : 3
- C6 : 4

A higher heat means a good place.
My approach was:

score = heat * time_spent
final_score = $\sum$ score/$\sum$time_spent.

According to this, 
A's score is:
((8*3) + (6*4) + (7*2))/(3+4+2) = 6.9

B's score is:
((2*3) + (3*4) + (4*2))/(3+4+2) = 2.9

According to this A visited cells with higher heat.

But as you may already notice this is not going to work.

**Why?**

Let's assume there is a person who visits  4 cells. Cells heats are 16, 1, 1, and 1. If he spent 1 minute in every cell except 16 one. if we assume he spent 2 minutes on it, his score is ((16*2)+(1*1)+(1*1)+(1*1))/5 = 7.00. But you can see he spent most of his time in a low heat place.
Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: I update the question

Comment: I have slimmed this down but left some puzzling details. For example, why mention a driver? Is this driver to be thought of differently from other people.

Comment: To determine what might be "correct," you need to specify what your "score" is intended to represent.  This question has no definite answer as stated in its abstract form.

Comment: I update question again to give more understand about what is main idea about this score. Please ask any question to clarify this.

Comment: I've edited presentation but so far as I can see this is just as vague as before. The frameworks of cells, heat, visitors seems incidental. You want some kind of weighted average. You have to be precise on why weighting by time spent is not good enough for your purpose,

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of correct ways to do this. The average (which you say is wrong) is one correct way. It may not answer the exact question that you have, but it's still a useful result. (By the way, it should be 16*1 if he spent one minute in each place; I edited that.)

If you want to totally discount outliers, you could look at the median by minute. Or you could look at the trimmed or Winsorized mean.